# Retrieving data from state and displaying it in dynamic form in antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In this line `{({languages}, {add, remove}) => ....` I am trying to put `languages` from state. But I have a problem referencing the state. The message `.map is not a function` appears. After pressing `Add another languages`, more inputs should appear with the possibility of choosing another language. I use library `antd`.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ycty22

```
import React from "react";
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Form,
  Button,
  Select,
  Space 
} from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';


const { Option } = Select;

const App = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        birthCountries: ['England', 'Germany', 'France'],
        birthCountry: '',
        languages: [{name: "German", level: "B1"}]
    });

    const {languages, birthCountries} = values;

    
    const Languages = () => {
        const onFinish = values => {
        console.log('Received values of form:', values);
    };


    return (
      
      <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
        <Form.List name="users">
          {({languages}, { add, remove }) => { //{languages} in this place I want to put languages 
                                               //from state
            return (
              <div>
                {languages.map(language => (
                  <Space key={language.name} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="start">
                    <Form.Item
                      label="Language"
                      {...language}
                      name={[language.name, 'first']}
                    >
                      <Select defaultValue={language.name} onChange={}>
                        {birthCountries.map((birthCountry, index) => {
                          return <Option value={birthCountry} key={index}>{birthCountry}</Option>
                        })}
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                      label="Level"
                      {...language}
                      name={[language.level, 'last']}
                    >
                      <Select defaultValue={language.level} onChange={}>
                        {birthCountries.map((birthCountry, index) => {
                          return <Option value={birthCountry} key={index}>{birthCountry}</Option>
                        })}
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
  
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(language.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  </Space>
                ))}
  
                <Form.Item>
                  <Button
                    type="dashed"
                    onClick={() => {
                      add();
                    }}
                    block
                  >
                    <PlusOutlined /> Add another Language
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Form.List>
      </Form>
    );
  };

    return (
        <div>
      {Languages()}
    </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Instead of `{({languages}, { add, remove }) => ...`, it should be `{(languages, { add, remove }) => ...`

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr that removes the error but does not give a solution to the real problem, that is to use the state info in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I found a way throw Ant Design documentation, which is quite non-intuitive when it comes to forms.

First of all you would like to set an `initialValues` to the `Form` component (the function that you use inside `Form.List` is not using languages from the scope, but rather as an argument that is feed as a Composed Element.

Later the most difficult part comes, you need to read the right value from the languages field. For that you substitute `name` prop in the `Form.item` for an array that points to `language.name` and then the second argument is the actual name of the field.

```
<Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off" initialValues={{ languages}}>
        <Form.List name="languages" >
          {(languages, {add, remove}) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {languages.map((language, index) => (
                  <Space key={language.name} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="start">
                    <Form.Item
                      label="Language"
                      {...language}
                      name={[language.name, 'name']}
                      fieldKey={[language.fieldKey, 'name']}
                    >
                      <Select onChange={}>
                        {birthCountries.map((birthCountry, index) => {
                          return <Option value={birthCountry} key={index}>{birthCountry}</Option>
                        })}
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                      label="Level"
                      {...language}
                      name={[language.name, 'level']}
                      fieldKey={[language.fieldKey, 'level']}
                    >
                      <Select onChange={}>
                        {birthCountries.map((birthCountry, index) => {
                          return <Option value={birthCountry} key={index}>{birthCountry}</Option>
                        })}
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
  
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(language.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  </Space>
                ))}
  
                <Form.Item>
                  <Button
                    type="dashed"
                    onClick={() => {
                      add();
                    }}
                    block
                  >
                    <PlusOutlined /> Add another Language
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Form.List>
      </Form>
    );
```

[You can see this working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogxzkk)

Hope this answer your question and help you. The API is a bit confusing as it is based on a `formik` way of doing things

Notes: In initialValues, is important that attribute that you use is name in the same way as the `Form.List` where you want to use the default value

Comment: I just updated it, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogxzkk

Comment: The problem after changing the values within the `Select` tags are fixed by giving a correct function to `onChange`

Comment: Could you check it @Umbro ?